# Download webpage in Firefox immediately? (hotkey)

Tags: firefox, internet

Is there any way to get a hotkey for page downloading in Firefox?

And if a page is already saved, **just rename it, but do not overwrite anything.**

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> will bookmark a page in Firefox

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will perform "Save Page As.."

Comment: But it will not download it.

Comment: Question rephrased.

Comment: @neverMind9 I've added a further option to my answer.

Comment: But that still requires another filename confirmation. And it might cause existing files to be overwritten.

Comment: @neverMind9 not if you move the saved file to a location other than the default.

Comment: …and that's the problem. On Windows, I made an AHK script to save by pressing Ctrl+S and putting a timestamp (_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS._) at the beginning of the filename. On Linux? Not sure how…

Comment: @neverMind9 "On Linux? Not sure how… " That is a whole new question which should be addressed as such, not here in comments. Refer back to this question if it helps when asking it.